# How do I know the patch version of my vim?

Tags: version

I have vim 7.4 installed, but I'm not sure what patch level it was at when I installed it. How do I check?

```
vim --version
```

Gives

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 15 2014 16:18:44)
....
```

But it doesn't give the patch level or a minor version number.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You seem to simply have an unpatched version of vim, otherwise the `:version` command or the `--version` parameter would list the patches on the second line. For example on my machine it says:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 10 2014 09:36:33)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-355, 357-430
```

This is "patchlevel" 430, but it skips patches 208 & 356.

Vim doesn't have a "minor version number" beyond *major.minor*; although I believe that some distributions may use the "patchlevel" as such.

---

As shown above, not all patches may be included, so if you want to use this value you can't just check if a number is higher than a certain version.

Usually, the best way is to use `has("patch-7.4-399")`; this will return true if:

- We're running Vim 7.4 with patch 399 included.
- We're running Vim 7.5 or later.

You can also use the form of `has('patch399')`, which is typically used like:

```
if v:version == 704 && has('patch399')
```

But be aware; this will be *false* for Vim 7.5; use this only in very specific cases.

See [`:help feature-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#feature-list) for some more information.

---

I can't find a way to list all the included patches, other than redirecting `:version` and parsing that ... I'm also not sure how this would be useful anyway, as `has()` should be enough :-)

Comment: Is it `has("patch-7.4-399")` or **`has("patch-7.4.399")`**? (the latter was suggested to me by some code-completion, and also seems to be **[what's actually described at the link you provided](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#feature-list)**)

Comment: @akavel They both work. You could even use `patch-7-4-399` ;-)

Comment: ahh, awsum, then :)

Comment: The `patch-7.4.399` format is only available after `7.4.237`.  See `:h has-patch`.

Comment: ↑ @blueyed is referring to the whole `has('patch-7.4-399')` feature of checking both the major.minor and the patch versions in one swoop (w/o resorting to `v:version`): independent of whether using `-` dashes or `.` dots.